# How to know the standby time of a disk before spinning down?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, hdparm

Under Linux, the command `hdparm` can change the idle time before next standby.

```
hdparm -S 120 /dev/hdc  #setting standby to 120 (10 minutes)
```

But how to know what was the previous setting?

Sadly, the info command gives nothing about that:

```
hdparm -I /dev/sdc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command will show the current spindown value, for example:

```
sudo hdparm -I /dev/sdb | grep level
```

Answer :

```
Advanced power management level: 254
```

From the [manual](https://linux.die.net/man/8/hdparm)
it seems that `254` is reserved, so I expect it to be Ubuntu's default:

> This timeout value is used by the drive to determine how long to wait (with no disk activity) before turning off the spindle motor to save power. Under such circumstances, the drive may take as long as 30 seconds to respond to a subsequent disk access, though most drives are much quicker. The encoding of the timeout value is somewhat peculiar. A value of zero means "timeouts are disabled": the device will not automatically enter standby mode. Values from 1 to 240 specify multiples of 5 seconds, yielding timeouts from 5 seconds to 20 minutes. Values from 241 to 251 specify from 1 to 11 units of 30 minutes, yielding timeouts from 30 minutes to 5.5 hours. A value of 252 signifies a timeout of 21 minutes. A value of 253 sets a vendor-defined timeout period between 8 and 12 hours, and the value 254 is reserved. 255 is interpreted as 21 minutes plus 15 seconds. Note that some older drives may have very different interpretations of these values.

Comment: Which system are you using? `hdparm -I ...` returns nothing related to `level` . I'm currently using v9.51 under Debian 9.

Comment: Which is your Linux?

Comment: Debian 9 64, hdparm is v9.51

Comment: Yes, it doesn't have it. What about `udisks --show-info /dev/sdb | grep spin`? It may require `udisk --ata-smart-refresh`.

Comment: While your answer helped me, I need to point out that the "advanced power management level" is not what OP asked for. He asked for the standby time, and it seems to be different from the power management level (although levels 128-254 do prohibit spindown). From the manual: -S is about idle mode and spindown timeout, and -B is about advanced power management.

Comment: @Rogach: There does not seem to be a way to query standby time with hdparm. There is only `hdparm -C` to see if the drive is on standby. This answer can at least set the time.

Comment: -1. This APM value does not represent a spin-down time.

Comment: @gertvdijk: "How to know the standby time of a disk **before spinning down**?"

Comment: @harrymc Yeah, you don't answer that. Your manpage excerpt is from the wrong section, so it's misleading imo. Look at `-B` instead, that's what it is reading back with `Advanced power management level` in `-I`: `-B     Get/set  Advanced Power Management feature, if the drive supports it. A low value means aggressive power management and a high value means better performance. Possible settings range from values 1 through 127 (which permit spin-down), [...]`.

Comment: @gertvdijk: That section is not related to timeout values.

Comment: @harrymc exactly! that's why your answer around `Advanced power management level` is *not* an answer to a question about the current/previous idle timeout values (as set by `-S <value>`).  It would have been an answer to a question how to get the current/previous setting to `-B`.

Answer (score 1):

### -B `APM_level` is not spindown timeout

-B     Get/set  Advanced Power Management feature, if the drive supports it.

Possible values are between 1 and 255,
low values mean more aggressive power management and
higher values mean better performance.

- 1 ~ 127 //permit spin-down (highest power management)
- 128 ~ 254 //not permit spin-down (highest performance)
- 255 //completely disables the feature

```
1     ~    127  |  128      ~      254  |  255
<--- spin-down  |  hi performance --->  | disable
```

### -S Get spindown timeout? //not possible

not blame to `hdparm`,
seems the low level comunication protocol not support that.
//not sure if any deivce impelment it privately.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/714966/116915

- 0       //disables spindown
- 1 ~ 240 //specify multiples of 5 seconds
- 241 ~ 251 //specify multiples of 30 minutes

-y //force immediately standby //spin down            //low power consumption
-Y //force immediately sleep   //shut down completely //lowest power consumption

### -J WD idle3 //not spindown timeout

-J     Get/set the Western Digital (WD) Green Drive's "idle3" timeout value.

This timeout controls how often the drive **parks its heads** and enters a low power consumption state.

WD green drive have a idle3 timeout,

> WD  supply  a WDIDLE3.EXE DOS utility for tweaking this setting, and you should use that program instead of hdparm if at all possible.
> The reverse-engineered implementation in hdparm
> is not as complete as the original official program, even though it does seem to work on at a least a few drives.